# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfirmata'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, pyfirmata

Hi I am trying to follow the tutorial here and (use pyfirmata to control Arduino IDE) and it is displaying the error message in title when I run python3 ./firmata.py

https://realpython.com/arduino-python/#the-arduino-platform

I downloaded pyfirmata using "pip3 install pyfirmata"
when I checked the python packages list in terminal I found it though:[image: proof]

code below (if helps)

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')

while True:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

output when runs python3 now: C:\Users\Abdulrahman\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Abdulrahman\firma.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Hope I was clear enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using VS code?

Comment: Yes I am.. Why?

Comment: Because I am also using VS code and this problem has happened to me before

Comment: Please update the question to add the output of this command `pip3 show pyfirmata` and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS code try to do *CTRL + SHIFT + P*, type settings.json and add this to json file:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:/Users/your_username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe"
}
```

In the example above I inserted python 3.12 as the interpreter version. Adjust it to your actual version of python installed in your computer.

After doing that restart VS code then uninstall and reinstall the *pyfirmata* package

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it did not fix the issue.